# Unable to run rubocop with ruby version managed by RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, rubocop

I am using `rvm` to manage ruby version. I am using ruby 2.5.0. I have also installed the `rubocop` gem in ruby `2.5.0`. I am getting below error while running `rubocop`.

I could see ruby version `2.5.0` when I run `rvm list`. Not sure where and how `rubocop` still looking for `ruby 2.1`.

```
Unknown Ruby version: 2.1
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:189:in `parser_class'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:197:in `create_parser'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:154:in `parse'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:36:in `initialize'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:17:in `new'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/processed_source.rb:17:in `from_file'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:349:in `get_processed_source'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:118:in `block in file_offenses'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:137:in `file_offense_cache'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:117:in `file_offenses'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:105:in `process_file'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:82:in `block in each_inspected_file'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:81:in `each'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:81:in `reduce'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:81:in `each_inspected_file'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:73:in `inspect_files'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/runner.rb:39:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:210:in `execute_runner'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:80:in `execute_runners'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:51:in `run'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/exe/rubocop:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rubocop-0.68.1/exe/rubocop:12:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you configure `TargetRubyVersion: 2.1` in your `.rubocop.yml`?

Comment: No, I haven't. Where do I find `.rubocop.yml`? or do I need to create one?

Comment: nevermind, I got the link https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#setting-the-target-ruby-version

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `ruboco.yml` in the project root directory and adding the below line fixed the issue.
[Ref](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#setting-the-target-ruby-version)

```
AllCops:
  TargetRubyVersion: 2.5.0
```

Comment: This worked, however, the filename should be `.rubocop.yml`.